# How to call super constructor from constructor with default params?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have two C++ classes, a base class and a sub class. The base class defines some properties and the sub class some others. Now, In the sub class the constructor is defined with several default parameters and it needs to include the default params from the base class, too. How do I do that?

Example:

```
// Base.h
class Base {
    protected:
        State _state;
        State _previousState;

    public: Base();
};

// Sub.h
class Sub : public Base {
    private:
        int _rate;
        int _checkCount;

    public: explicit Sub(int sampleRate);
};

// Sub.cpp
Sub::Sub(int rate)
    :_state(Silent),
    _previousState(Running),
    _rate(rate),
    _checkCount(0)
{
}
```

Obviously, in Sub.ccp constructor the _state and _previousState args are misplaced. How can I integrate them properly into this construction?

Comment: Please prefer "derived" and "base" and use the terms consistently. "Sub" and "super" are confusing; flipping between the two sets of terminology is even worse...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you can offer a default construct function with default values for the base class**

---

```
// Base.h
class Base {
    protected:
        State _state;
        State _previousState;

    public: Base( State a =Silent,State b =Runing):_state(a), _previousState(b){}
};

// Sub.h
class Sub : public Base {
    private:
        int _rate;
        int _checkCount;

    public: explicit Sub(int sampleRate);
};

// Sub.cpp
Sub::Sub(int rate)
    _rate(rate),
    _checkCount(0)
{
}
```

---

**another way: since the data member in the base class is protected,you can change its value in the constructor function body of the sub class**

```
// Base.h
    class Base {
        protected:
            State _state;
            State _previousState;

        public: Base( );
    };

// Sub.h
class Sub : public Base {
    private:
        int _rate;
        int _checkCount;

    public: explicit Sub(int sampleRate);
};

// Sub.cpp
    Sub::Sub(int rate)
        _rate(rate),
        _checkCount(0)
    {
     _state=Slience;
     _previousState=Running;
    }
```

Comment: You might get more upvotes if you added some explanation to your answer.

Comment: assigning the values in the subclass ctor body works fine too, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 5):

By giving the base constructor some parameters, and invoking it with arguments:

```
Base::Base(State state = {}, State previousState = {})
   : _state(state)
   , _previousState(previousState)
{}

// ...

Sub::Sub(int rate)
   : Base(Silent, Running)
   , _rate(rate)
   , _checkCount(0)
{}
```

Comment: Thanks! However that defines the constructor already in the header file. What if I wanted to have the actual constructor implementation in Base.cpp instead?

Comment: @hexagonstar: I don't follow.

Comment: Maybe I'm just misunderstanding this. If I provide braces for a ctor in a .h file that means it's defined there but if the braces for a ctor are not in the .h file they should be defined in the .cpp file, no? Or does it matter at all where it's defined (I suppose so)?

Comment: @hexagonstar: Sorry, got no idea what you're asking. I've shown you what your constructor's parameter lists and definitions could look like. It's up to you as to how you want to arrange the declarations and definitions, as you would with any other constructors and member functions.

Comment: Still new to C++ and confused as to why constructor implementation can be defined in header files. But I'm getting the hang of it, thanks!

Comment: @hexagonstar: Well, it can. But my answer did not show that, so not sure why you're bringing it up.